# Modify a column in first n rows based on other column value in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to modify a column in first n rows based on other column value in a DataFrame. Like this:

```
df.loc[(df.A == i), 'B'][0:10] = 100
```

It did not work.
Things I have also tried is sampling first n rows like this:

```
(df.sample(10)).loc[(df.A == i), 'B'] = 100
```

But It returned `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `head` and `loc` like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.arange(100),'B':[1]*100})

df.loc[df[(df.A % 2 == 0)].head(10).index,'B'] = 100

print(df.head(25))
```

Output:

```
     A    B
0    0  100
1    1    1
2    2  100
3    3    1
4    4  100
5    5    1
6    6  100
7    7    1
8    8  100
9    9    1
10  10  100
11  11    1
12  12  100
13  13    1
14  14  100
15  15    1
16  16  100
17  17    1
18  18  100
19  19    1
20  20    1
21  21    1
22  22    1
23  23    1
24  24    1
```

Answer (score 2):

I can only come up with this

```
df.loc[(df.A==i)&(df.index.isin(df.iloc[:10,:].index)),'B']=100
```

For the `sample` , this will work

```
s=(df.sample(10))
s.loc[(df.A == i), 'B'] = 100
```

And base on discussion on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11984)

***You should NEVER do this type of chained inplace setting. It is simply bad practice.***

PS : `(df.sample(10)).loc[(df.A == i), 'B'] = 100` #*this is chained inplace setting*

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work. Anyway, @Scott's answer is what I needed.